# Google Assistant Actions - Device Location

Tags: actions-on-google

How can I get user device location (lat, lng) in Google Actions? I have found some examples using `actions-on-google` library to ask user for permission and get device location. But when creating a new project it is using `@assistant/conversation` instead of `actions-on-google`. If I understand correctly, this conversation lib is a new standard and I should be using it.
Unfortunately, I cannot find any information about permissions or device location in `@assistant/conversation`. Is there some other library I should use? Or maybe it is still in development and I should stick to older `actions-on-google` until it will be ready?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google released an update of their Google Action docs and now there is a section how to request and obtain the user's location, please see here: https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/permissions