# Get Device Location - Google Assistant

Tags: actions-on-google

I am using @assistant/conversation and I need to get the user’s device location in one of the handlers. I can’t find any documentation about this. There used to be permission helpers in actions sdk which could be used to get the exact location, but there is no information about implementing this in the conversational actions and nothing about requesting permissions in the [Fulfillment Migration Docs](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/fulfillment-migration#fulfillment_code_translation_map) as well. This is what I am trying to implement. [Permissions](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/df-asdk/helpers#calling_the_helper)

I also found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64914584/google-assistant-actions-device-location) which is still unanswered.